# I need help writing a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks like the following (usually more than 2 records)

```
OBLIGOR  OBN_NUM     XPTYPE NET_UNUSED BANK_ASSET 
-------------------------------------------------
 1       000100000   0101    100         0
 1       000100001   5151    100         0
 1       000100002   5151     50         0
```

When I use the following SQL I am able to sum as 100 only. But I want to get 250.

```
SELECT  
    SUM(NET_UNUSED) + SUM(BANK_ASSET) AS BANK_ASSET,  
    OBLIGOR AS OBLIGOR, 
    SUBSTRING (OBN_NUM,1,4) AS OBN_NUM
FROM 
    RB_CRM_DEV.[IN].STG_SF_I_DC
WHERE 
    SUBSTRING (OBN_NUM,1,4) = SUBSTRING (OBN_NUM,1,4)
    AND SUBSTRING( XPTYPE,1,1) IN (0,1)
GROUP BY  
    OBLIGOR, SUBSTRING (OBN_NUM, 1, 4)
ORDER BY
    OBLIGOR, SUBSTRING(OBN_NUM, 1, 4)
```

How do I make sure my set of record should have `xptype as 0,1` for at least record to check in this query (since `SUBSTRING(XPTYPE,1,1) IN (0,1)` condition drops the other two records).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your `XPTYPE` has 4 characters. What do you mean when you say it has an xptype as 0,1? It looks like maybe you want to check if the second character is a 0 or a 1? Or do you mean that xtype must have one of 0 or 1 anywhere in it?

Comment: out of the multiple records, atleast one record have first character of xptype as either 0 or 1

Comment: So sum all rows for `OBLIGOR,SUBSTRING(OBN_NUM,1,4)` as long as any row for that combination begins with a 1 or 0?

Comment: it is my bad. since all three records fall into my aggregation (since substr(obn_num,1,4) are same, but i want to check only record have first character of xptype as either 0 or 1.

Comment: Please stop explaining what you mean in comments, and instead [edit] the question to make it more clear there where it can be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I've understood your requirement correctly, then what you're after is the existence of any record for an Obligor that has an xptype which begins with 0 or 1, as such you can use `EXISTS` to check for this:

```
SELECT  SUM(NET_UNUSED)+SUM(BANK_ASSET) AS BANK_ASSET,  OBLIGOR AS OBLIGOR, 
  SUBSTRING (OBN_NUM,1,4) AS OBN_NUM
FROM RB_CRM_DEV.[IN].STG_SF_I_DC A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM RB_CRM_DEV.[IN].STG_SF_I_DC B
  WHERE SUBSTRING (A.OBN_NUM,1,4) = SUBSTRING (B.OBN_NUM,1,4)
    AND A.OBLIGOR = B.OBLIGOR
    AND SUBSTRING( B.XPTYPE,1,1) IN (0,1)
  )
GROUP BY  OBLIGOR, SUBSTRING (OBN_NUM,1,4)
ORDER by OBLIGOR,SUBSTRING(OBN_NUM,1,4)
```

Should work. If this wasn't what you wanted, then please edit your question with more example data to show exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One more way using join -

```
SELECT Sum(t1.net_unused) + Sum(t1.bank_asset) AS BANK_ASSET, 
       t1.obligor                              AS OBLIGOR, 
       Substring (t1.obn_num, 1, 4)            AS OBN_NUM 
FROM   rb_crm_dev.[IN].stg_sf_i_dc t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT obligor, 
                          obn_num 
                   FROM   rb_crm_dev.[IN].stg_sf_i_dc 
                   WHERE  Substring(xptype, 1, 1) IN ( 0, 1 )) t2 
               ON t1.obligor = t2.obligor 
                  AND Substring (t1.obn_num, 1, 4) = 
                      Substring (t2.obn_num, 1, 4) 
GROUP  BY t1.obligor, 
          t1.Substring (obn_num, 1, 4) 
ORDER  BY t1.obligor, 
          t1.Substring(obn_num, 1, 4)
```